# Checking Blocking with `poll()`

Tags: c, posix

I want to check if a file descriptor would block on a certain event and I got the idea of using `poll()` with a 0 timeout:

```
int wouldblock(int fd, short event)
{
  struct pollfd pfd;
  pfd.fd = fd;
  pfd.events = event;
  return (poll(&pfd,1,0) == 0);
}

...
  if (wouldblock(0,POLLIN)) ...
...
```

Either the stream is available, and poll() should return 1, or it would block and the timeout will kick in returning 0. (Let's set aside error checking for a moment).

It works (at least "*it works on my machine*") but I wonder if I did miss anything?
Maybe `poll()` is overkill and I'm stressing the system too much?

Comment: `F_GETFL O_NONBLOCK`?

Comment: My understanding is that way I would get if the stream is capable of blocking. My intention (and what the code does) is to check if the stream would block if a read or write would be performed.

Comment: In general the utility of `poll` or `select` is in them allowing you to wait simultaneously on *multiple* open file descriptors until one of them becomes ready. If you're just checking a single stream, then you could just use non-blocking operations.

Comment: @KamilCuk: `O_NONBLOCK` queries if the file is set so that file operations that would block will return immediately with an error of `EWOULDBLOCK` or `EAGAIN`. This is not what OP was asking for.

Comment: I think, your code is a textbook example of usage of `poll` - this is exactly what it was designed for.

Comment: @gstukelj Agreed, but then I would have to perform the read/write operation. I wanted to check *without* having to actually perform the operation.

Comment: @SergeyA Yes, my concern is exactly that since it is designed to check multiple file descriptors, using it just for one might be uselessly expensive.

Comment: @Remo.D it is designed to prevent blocking operations from being called. Could multiple or single fds. There is no other operations (barring `poll` siblings such as `select`, `epoll`, etc) which would give you the behavior you are looking for.

Comment: Could you share with us why you need the check if a single file descriptor would block? I fear that your program will use all available CPU in a loop only checking if something has to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder if I did miss anything?

`poll` can return immediately, and the operation still can block. This can happen because there is time between returning from `poll()` and starting the operation. This happens when an event happens that changes the state of the thing that is connected to the file descriptor, and that event happens after your process returns from `poll()` and is about to start the operation.

The most common case, two processes concurrently `poll()`ing and `read()`ing from one pipe - it can happen that both `poll` return, but only one `read` wins.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
int main(void)
{
    system("mkfifo /tmp/fifo ; echo > /tmp/fifo & sleep 0.1");
    fork();
    int fd = open("/tmp/fifo", O_RDWR);
    sleep(1);
    printf("poll=%d\n", (int)poll(&(struct pollfd){fd, POLLIN}, 1, 0));
    sleep(1);
    printf("read=%d\n", (int)read(fd, (char[1]){}, 1));
    printf("%d exiting!\n", (int)getppid());
    wait(0);
}
```

outputs with enough luck:

```
poll=1
poll=1
read=1
136769 exiting!
```

and the other `fork()`ed process is waiting on `read`.

I remember seeing also on kernel mailing list a thread with a feature that would drop old network packets to prevent stall. With such a feature a program could: `poll()` on a network socket, then kernel decides to drop the packet, then process does `read()` only to discover the packet is no longer there.

Use `poll()` as a "notification" system - `poll()` returns file descriptors that you should "check" if they have something to read from. Then you should check "for real" if there is something to read by calling `read()`.

In a real application, I would move the "wouldblock" function [up one layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) and instead of checking if a file descriptor would block, I would check if a full logical packet in whatever protocol I'm using was received. Call it `has_received_a_packet` that would receive data with `read()` with `O_NONBLOCK`, accumulate in a buffer and check if a full packet was received.

> Maybe poll() is overkill and I'm stressing the system too much?

I believe so, you could straight call `read` and just receive that data on the spot. Similar to how `ungetc` is implemented:

```
struct buf {
   char data;
   bool hasit;
};
int readbuf_has_something(struct buf *readbuf, int fd) {
    if (!readbuf->hasit) {
        set_nonblock(fd);
        ssize_t r = read(fd, &readbuf->data, 1);
        if (r == 1) readbuf->hasit = 1;
        if (ret < 0) return -EIO;
    }
    return readbuf->hasit;
}
int readbuf_something(struct buf *readbuf, int fd) {
    if (readbuf->hasit) {
      readbuf->hasit = 0;
      return readbuf.data;
    }
    set_block(fd);
    ssize_t r = read(fd, &readbuf->data, 1);
    if (r == 1) return readbuf->data;
    return EOF;
}
```

Such implementation would result in one less context change then using `poll` followed by `read` - just read the data, they are there.